# Create and Reap Multiple Child Processes

Tags: c, fork, wait, zombie-process

I've been unable to figure out how to fork off multiple (anywhere from 10 - 200) child processes and have the parent process wait for all of them to complete. I am trying to benchmark their cumulative execution time.

Despite my best efforts, I've been getting very random results and processes are being shown as 'Z' (zombie) when I watch it with top.

My code is below, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
int child_pid;
int status, wait_pid;

for(i = 0; i < instances; i++){
    if((child_pid = fork()) < 0){ // an error occured
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(child_pid == 0){ 
        // Child process --------------------------------------------------
        fprintf(stdout, "Child with PID: %d is in if code.", getpid());

        // Calculate pi using statistical methode across all iterations
        for(i=0; i<iterations; i++){
            x = (random() % (RADIUS * 2)) - RADIUS;
            y = (random() % (RADIUS * 2)) - RADIUS;
            if(zeroDist(x,y) < RADIUS){
                inCircle++;
            }

            inSquare++;
        }

        /* Finish calculation */
        pCircle = inCircle/inSquare;
        piCalc = pCircle * 4.0;

        /* Print result */
        fprintf(stdout, "pi = %f\n", piCalc);

        _Exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); //child is done ------------------------------
    }
}

//Parent Process
while ((wait_pid = wait(&status)) > 0){
    printf("Exit status of %d was %d \n", (int)wait_pid, status);
}

fprintf(stdout, "Bye from: %d.\n", getpid());
return 0;
```

EDIT:

To measure my results, I am simply calling the program from the command line using the Linux time command.

`> /usr/bin/time ./pi-sched`

EDIT2:

The rest of my code contains the below two functions and a bunch of command line parsing and setup procedures; nothing else relevant to the computation.

```
inline double dist(double x0, double y0, double x1, double y1){
    return sqrt(pow((x1-x0),2) + pow((y1-y0),2));
}

inline double zeroDist(double x, double y){
    return dist(0, 0, x, y);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `WNOHANG`?  This is going to cause it to return a 0 immediately without updating `status` if no child has yet terminated.  Why not just use `wait` or pass `0` for `options`?

Comment: I understood it that `WNOHANG` would allow the parent to continue if there were no children left to reap. But you're saying simply having `pid_t done = wait(&status);` will give me the desired result?

Comment: Yes.  `wait(&status)` will return immediately with `-1` and `errno == ECHILD` if there are no children to wait for.  Otherwise, it will block until a child exits, returning its pid, and exit status.

Answer (score 0):

> processes are being shown as 'Z' (zombie) when I watch it with top.

That is because you do not start wait the child processes unless you finished the `for(i = 0; i < instances; i++){` loop. To wait child process as soon as possible, you could put that call to `waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)` in this `for()` loop, this `waitpid()` will return immediately if there is no terminated child process.

> I've been getting very random results

The execuation time of your program depends how expensive the following code could be:

```
        x = (random() % (RADIUS * 2)) - RADIUS;
        y = (random() % (RADIUS * 2)) - RADIUS;
        if(zeroDist(x,y) < RADIUS){
            inCircle++;
        }
```

Because `x` and `y` are some random values, the execution time of the above code may also change randomly.

Comment: I've made an edit to show how I've been measuring, thanks for the clarification question. As far as calling wait, how would you suggest I do that so I ensure my parent process has exited the for loop before the children start turning into zombies?

Comment: @Forerunner117 You could put that `waitpid()` in the `for` loop. Please check out my updated answer.

Comment: If I put that in the for loop, would it not be waiting on each child before moving on and creating a new child? I'm trying to have all processes execute simultaneously to benchmark different Linux process schedulers. But yes, you are correct that the randomized nature of the computation should produce varied results, but not as varied as I've been seeing I don't think.

Comment: @Forerunner117 If you use `waitpid(..., WNOHANG)`, `waitpid()` will return immediately if there is no terminated child process.

Comment: @Forerunner117 About the varied execution time, I need the full code to do further diagnosis. If it is possible, please include the full code in your question.

Comment: @Forerunner117 After filled some missed parts of your code, I create a test program, but it does not show any wild execution time change.

Comment: I just saw your most recent comment from yesterday; sorry for the late response. I edited my code in my original post to what I'm currently working on. It seems to work on a small scale, but gives variation on a larger scale (60-200 processes with 10,000,000 iterations of pi-calc).

Comment: @Forerunner117 You realize that I have to fill in all those missing pieces in your code in order to test it, and I may insert some code that may lead to wrong conclusion, right? Why do you not post your whole source code and the test results (including any relevant inputs)?

Comment: I apologize for failing to be explicit with my code. However, I have just solved my issue: My native installation of Linux is apparently on the fritz; running the exact same code on a VM running a stable distro of Ubuntu gives me very steady results across multiple runs. I appreciate all the time you took to help me out, and thanks for sticking with me on this. I'd vote you up, but my rep is unfotunately too low for that.

Comment: @Forerunner117 I am glad that your problem got solved.